# Errot: Can not catkin build Onboard-SDK-ROS

Tags: dji-sdk

I built along this page.

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/sample-setup.html#linux-oes

But, the following error occurred.
Do you know the solution?

Errors     << dji_sdk:make /home/robotics/catkin_ws/logs/dji_sdk/build.make.001.log
/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp: In member function ‘bool DJISDKNode::missionStatusCallback(dji_sdk::MissionStatus::Request&, dji_sdk::MissionStatus::Response&)’:
/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp:20:62: error: ‘class DJI::OSDK::MissionManager’ has no member named ‘wayptCounter’
   response.waypoint_mission_count = vehicle->missionManager->wayptCounter;
                                                              ^
/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp:21:62: error: ‘class DJI::OSDK::MissionManager’ has no member named ‘hotptCounter’
   response.hotpoint_mission_count = vehicle->missionManager->hotptCounter;
                                                              ^
/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp: In member function ‘bool DJISDKNode::missionWpActionCallback(dji_sdk::MissionWpAction::Request&, dji_sdk::MissionWpAction::Response&)’:
/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp:131:32: error: ‘class DJI::OSDK::MissionManager’ has no member named ‘wayptCounter’
   if (vehicle->missionManager->wayptCounter == 0)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4P6j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Onboard-SDK-ROS 3.7 (latest commit months ago) does not build on top of Onboard-SDK 3.8 (latest commit 9 days ago) which removed wayptCounter and hotptCounter.

Best solution: DJI release Onboard-SDK-ROS with support for the new features of Onboard-SDK 3.8.

Immediate solution: Downgrade Onboard-SDK to 3.7 so that Onboard-SDK-ROS 3.7 is supported.  The DJI instructions you followed are broken until DJI release Onboard-SDK-ROS 3.8 (or DJI change their Onboard-SDK-ROS instructions to download the older Onboard-SDK 3.7).

Last year Onboard-SDK 3.7 and Onboard-SDK-ROS 3.7 were released on the same day so this problem didn't happen, it is disappointing that they are now out of sync, breaking builds like yours.

I also notice that the Onboard-SDK 3.8 README.md from 2019-04-03 links to the [latest release notes](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/appendix/releaseNotes.html), which starts with "Release Notes for Onboard SDK 3.6 2018-08-14 3.7 OSDK 3.7 Highlights".

I hope that someone at DJI is about to update the Onboard-SDK release notes to 3.8 and push commits to release Onboard-SDK-ROS 3.8.